# How to bulk insert data from ref cursor to a temporary table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

Could anyone tell me how to bulk insert data from a ref cursor to a temporary table in PL/SQL? I have a procedure that one of its parameters stores a result set, this result set will be inserted to a temporary table in another stored procedure.

This is my sample code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_account_list
(
type_id in account_type.account_type_id%type,
acc_list out sys_refcursor
)
is
begin
    open acc_list for
    select account_id, account_name, balance
    from account
    where account_type_id = type_id;
end get_account_list;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1
(
   ...
)
is
    accounts sys_refcursor;
begin
    get_account_list(1, accounts);

    --How to bulk insert data in accounts to a temporary table?


end proc1;
```

In SQL Server, I can write as code below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_account_list    
   type_id int
as
   select account_id, account_name, balance
   from account
   where account_type_id = type_id;



CREATE PROCEDURE proc1
(
  ...
)
as
   ...

   insert into #tmp_data(account_id, account_name, balance)
   exec get_account_list 1
```

How can I write similar to the code in SQL Server? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use BULK operations on REF CURSOR:

```
SQL> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE gt (ID NUMBER);

Table crÚÚe.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3     TYPE tab_number IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  4     l_data tab_number;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN l_refcursor FOR
  7        SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1e6;
  8     LOOP
  9        FETCH l_refcursor BULK COLLECT
 10           INTO l_data LIMIT 100;
 11
 12        FORALL i IN 1..l_data.count
 13           INSERT INTO gt VALUES (l_data(i));
 14
 15        EXIT WHEN l_refcursor%NOTFOUND;
 16
 17     END LOOP;
 18     CLOSE l_refcursor;
 19  END;
 20  /

ProcÚdure PL/SQL terminÚe avec succÞs.
```

Oracle 10g already implements this optimization for regular loop though, so you may not see much improvement from a simple LOOP...INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
procedure insert_rec(in_type_id in number) is 
   begin
   insert into temp_table 
   select account_id, account_name, balance
   from account
   where account_type_id = in_type_id;
end insert_rec;
```

Comment: It's not that easy. My code is just a sample. The procedure get_account_list has many calculations inside and finally comes up with a result set which is transfered to other procedures through parameter acc_list. Thanks.