# need to get the output of 2 cursors in one temp table

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor, oracle11g, procedure

Here is my first procedure (sample)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GPTOWNER_CORP_AMF.testt1
AS
po_status VARCHAR2(100);
po_cur_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
po_cur_2 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN po_cur_1 FOR
select app_var_row_seq,app_var_name,app_var_value,app_var_description,r_date
 from TMP_PMT_APP_VARIABLES_REF
where ROWNUM < 5;

OPEN po_cur_2 FOR
select config_to_lob_row_seq,config_row_seq,lobref_row_seq,r_date
 from  TMP_PMT_CONFIG_TO_LOB_DAT 
 where ROWNUM < 6;
 TESTT2(po_cur_1,po_cur_2,po_status);
 DBMS_output.put_line(po_status);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM||SQLCODE);
END;
```

Here is my second procedure (sample)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure GPTOWNER_CORP_AMF.testt2 (pi_cur_1 IN sys_refcursor, pi_cur_2 IN sys_refcursor,po_status OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
app_var_row_seq NUMBER;
app_var_name VARCHAR2(100);
app_var_value VARCHAR2(1000);
app_var_description VARCHAR2(1000);
r_date1 DATE;
config_to_lob_row_seq NUMBER;
config_row_seq VARCHAR2(100);
lobref_row_seq NUMBER;
r_date2 DATE;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH pi_cur_1 into app_var_row_seq,app_var_name,app_var_value,app_var_description,r_date1;
        FETCH pi_cur_2 into config_to_lob_row_seq,config_row_seq,lobref_row_seq,r_date2;

        EXIT WHEN (pi_cur_2%NOTFOUND AND pi_cur_1%NOTFOUND ) ; 

        INSERT INTO testt1testt2 (colid,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) 
                    VALUES(colid.nextval,app_var_row_seq,app_var_name,app_var_value,app_var_description,r_date1,config_to_lob_row_seq,config_row_seq,lobref_row_seq,r_date2);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('rows inserted:' || pi_cur_1%ROWCOUNT || 'and' || pi_cur_2%ROWCOUNT);   
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM||SQLCODE);
END;
```

---

My problem statement is that from first procedure I am getting two refcursor as output and in the second procedure I am trying to read them and put them into a temp table which will be used by another procedure. Cant union the two select statements as they are having different set of output. Is there any better mechanism to do so , as by my approach I am facing issue as when I run the first procedure (say first select return 4 row and second select return 6 rows) the need is that 6 rows would be inserted into temp table but the columns that are read from first select will be inserted as NULL when there is now row fetched , but in my case duplicate row is getting inserted. Any help would be appreciated. And do post if anyone needs more info on the same.

Comment: No, your actual problem is that you are populating a table with values from two other tables without +defining a relationship between them+. At the moment, your first run could produce records in `testt1testt2` constructed from (TMP_PMT_APP_VARIABLES_REF **#1**, TMP_PMT_CONFIG_TO_LOB_DAT **#2**) and (TMP_PMT_APP_VARIABLES_REF **#2**, TMP_PMT_CONFIG_TO_LOB_DAT **#1**). Then the next run would have (TMP_PMT_APP_VARIABLES_REF **#2**, TMP_PMT_CONFIG_TO_LOB_DAT **#2**) and (TMP_PMT_APP_VARIABLES_REF **#1**, TMP_PMT_CONFIG_TO_LOB_DAT **#1**). Which is frankly nonsensical.

Comment: if you have been given requirement A you should deliver A , but not prove A = Z and deliver Z, iterations can be of any order that is not issue as long as data is inserted into temp table. Makes sense ?

Comment: No it does not make sense.  You want to populate a new table (`t_new`) with columns from two existing tables (`t1`, `t2`).  I would expect there to be some business logic defining the join between `t1` and `t2`.  But you haven't got any.  So basically you are populating `t_new` with records produced by welding random rows from `t1` to random rows in `t2`.   Programming is an exercise in  logic and part of the job description is challenging "requirements" which are incomplete, ambiguous or just plain wrong.

Comment: Out of my curiosity , if I ask  there is  a relation between the two tables (take r_date as the common column). Can you throw light on the approach but dont modify the first procedure as it still has to return two ref cursors as given.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, then you don't really need to union them - but join them.
Since there is no really relation between the 2 tables and you want nulls in "both side"s you need to `full outer join` them.

I will not ask you, why you want them both on the same temp table if there is no relation between them. But if you do this why not just use an `insert-select` ?

```
INSERT INTO testt1testt2 (colid,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) 
SELECT colid.nextval, app_var_row_seq,app_var_name,app_var_value,app_var_description, t1.r_date,
                      config_to_lob_row_seq,config_row_seq,lobref_row_seq, t2.r_date
FROM (select app_var_row_seq,app_var_name,app_var_value,app_var_description,r_date
      from TMP_PMT_APP_VARIABLES_REF
      where ROWNUM < 5) t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN (select config_to_lob_row_seq,config_row_seq,lobref_row_seq,r_date
                 from  TMP_PMT_CONFIG_TO_LOB_DAT 
                 where ROWNUM < 6) t2 on 1=2
```

---

**UPDATE:**
If the requirement is to get 2 refcursors, then my approach isn't relevant...
What you can do though, is have 2 insert commands one like this:

```
INSERT INTO testt1testt2 (colid,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) 
     VALUES (colid.nextval,app_var_row_seq,app_var_name,app_var_value,app_var_descript‌​ion,r_date1,null,null,null,null);
```

and the other like:

```
INSERT INTO testt1testt2 (colid,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9)
     VALUES (colid.nextval,null,null,null,null,null,config_to_lob_row_seq,config_row_s‌​eq,lobref_row_seq,r_date2);
```

If you really want to do it nicely, you can use `bulk insert` for performance, see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2431606/1083652)

Comment: By meaning union I should have conveyed them as JOIN , but having a FULL OUTER JOIN may impact performance if the data is many (your points on it !!!) . And regarding the temp table I need it because that is the requirement set as : They will give me 2 refcursor as input and I should give them 1 temptable holding all the data that is fetched from the refcursor. And it would be really nice if it can be explained how can I modify/implement this "insert-select" to my above explained solution approach.

Comment: You tracked me on the right way "BULK INSERT/COLLECT" is what I was thinking too in my hindsight, but how to insert into a single table using BULK mechanism which will read two ref cursor. I know I am asking for spoon-feeding but it would be really nice if I could get at least a link or two.

Comment: Ok got it , I can have 2 insert statements , but I guess by doing that it will insert 4+5=9 rows in the temp table (for the above ex) , but what I thought was having 5 rows in the temp table (i.e. - max of the two cursors = no of row insert in the temp table) . If there is no other way around then I guess I have to go by two inserts. Please suggest.